# Supremum of the product of two sets

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Here is a GRE math subject problem:

> **63.** For any nonempty sets $A,B\subseteq \Bbb R$, let $A\cdot B$ be the set defined by
>   $$A\cdot B=\{xy\,:\, x\in A\wedge y\in B\}$$
>   If $A$ and $B$ are nonempty bounded sets and if $\sup A>\sup B$, then $\sup(A\cdot B)=$
>
> (A) $\quad\sup(A)\sup( B)$
>
> (B) $\quad\sup(A)\inf(B)$
>
> (C) $\quad\max\{\sup(A)\sup(B),\ \inf(A)\inf(B)\}$
>
> (D) $\quad\max\{\sup(A)\sup(B),\ \sup(A)\inf(B)\}$
>
> (E) $\quad\max\{\sup(A)\sup(B),\ \inf(A)\sup(B),\ \inf(A)\inf(B)\}$

The answer is E while I thought it was C.

When could $\inf(A)\sup(B)=\sup(A\cdot B)$ under the condition $\sup(A)>\sup(B)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance, when $\inf A>0$ and $\sup B<0$. Since all the products will be negative, you want to minimise the absolute values of each factor.

Comment: Thank you for answering and editing~~I was a little bit lazy in typing those words :)

Comment: You're welcome. Check ajotatxe's answer, which gives a complete caracterisation of what you ask.

Answer (score 0):

When $\inf B<0$, $|\inf B|\ge \sup B$, $\sup A>0$ and $\sup A\ge |\inf A|$.